# Netsuite Client Script to create popup when certain items added to a sales order

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I am trying to create a client script to show a message when certain items are added to a sales order. This can be either immediately after the item is added or when the order is saved.

I have tried the below script but it is coming up with the attached error.

```
function onSaveTriggerPopup (){

 listText = [1883,1882]; // Change list of Internal Ids in this Array
 //get the number of line items in the SO item sublist
 var numLine = nlapiGetLineItemCount('item', 'item');
 //Define the boolean variable to record if there is a match found between internal ID list and the line item internal ID
 var found = false;
 //loop over each line item to check item internal ID
 for (var i = 1; i <= numLine; i++) {
     //get line item internal ID
     var ID = nlapiGetLineItemValue('item', 'item', i);
     //check if current item internal ID is inside the internal ID list
     //This will return '-1' if no match found, and return the index number for a match
     var returnCode = listArray.indexOf(ID);
     //check if a match found, if this is true, the script will set bool variable found to be true
     if (returnCode != '-1') {
         found = true;
         nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'found an line item with internalID: ' + ID, '-');
         break;
     }
 }
 //pop-up alert window if a match found
 if (found == true) {
     alert("Have you added a partner?");
 }

 }
```

[Error Message received](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6ZjZ.png)

Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by this line:

```
 var returnCode = listArray.indexOf(ID);
```

The listArray variable is undefinied.

Comment: Thanks vVinceth, how do i define this?